# Adding code to a preexisting method

Tags: java, methods

Just having a hard time adding a certain bit of given code to add an extra check to a preexisting method.

```
public boolean makeAppointment(int time,
                               Appointment appointment)
{
    if(validTime(time)) {
        int startTime = time - START_OF_DAY;
        if(appointments[startTime] == null) {
            int duration = appointment.getDuration();
            // Fill in all the slots for the full duration
            // of the appointment.
            for(int i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
                appointments[startTime + i] = appointment;
            }
            return true;
        }
        else {

            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is the main makeAppointment method. I need to add a method that checks if one appoints duration overlaps that of another. If I have two appointments: 1 is at 5PM and lasts 2 hours, the other is at 6 PM and only last one hour. I need to add the following method into this preexisting code to prevent this from happening.

```
private boolean checkMultihourAppointment(int startTime, int duration){
```

Thats the header for it. I have tried to implement it, but it ends up failing every Junit test.

Need any more info, please ask :)

Comment: I am drawing a complete blank. The only thing I can thing of is to check if the appointment slot ISNT null. So:
private boolean checkMultihourAppointment(int startTime, int duration){
     if(appointments[startTime] != null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No!");
     }
  return false;
    
    }

Comment: Don't just erase the contents of a question; why would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?  Rewrite your existing code to add checkmethod.

```
public boolean makeAppointment(int time,
                               Appointment appointment)
{
    if(validTime(time)) {
        int startTime = time - START_OF_DAY;
        int duration = appointment.getDuration();
        if(checkMultihourAppointment(startTime, duration)) {
            // Fill in all the slots for the full duration
            // of the appointment.
            for(int i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
                appointments[startTime + i] = appointment;
            }
            return true;
        }
        else {

            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean checkMultihourAppointment(int startTime, int duration){
    for(int i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
          if(appointments[startTime + i] != null) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified code is easier to work with: code turned on its side is not a graph of how awesome it is.

```
public boolean makeAppointment(int time, Appointment appointment) {
    if (!validTime(time)) {
        return false;
    }

    int startTime = time - START_OF_DAY;
    if (appointments[startTime] != null) {
        return false;
    }

    int duration = appointment.getDuration();

    // Here's where the new code goes
    if (appointmentOverlaps(time, duration)) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
        appointments[startTime + i] = appointment;
    }

    return true;
}
```

`appointmentOverlaps` will check the next `duration` appointment slots for `null` (empty):

```
// Pseudo-code
public boolean appointmentOverlaps(int time, int duration) {
    while (appointment still going) {
        if (next slot filled) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Consider returning some sort of status so the caller knows *why* an appointment was rejected.

`appointmentOverlaps` should also handle the existing code's `startTime` check, simplifying further.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean checkMultihourAppointment(int startTime, int duration){

    for (int i = startTime; i <= startTime + duration; i++){

        if (appointments[i] != null)
            return false;

    }

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it properly...

#### Step 1

Employ good object oriented design and add a method to `Appointment` that checks for overlapping with another `Appointment`, so the implementation is hidden away *inside* the `Appointment` class where it belongs

```
public class Appointment {
    Date start;
    int minutesDuration; // recommend change this to a Date

    public boolean overlaps(Appointment other) {
        // Check for any overlap by comparing opposite ends of each other
        return start.before(other.getEnd()) && getEnd().after(other.start);
    }

    private Date getEnd() {
        return new Date(start + minutesDuration * 60 * 1000);
    }
}
```

#### Step 2

Use this method in your code:

```
if (appointment.overlaps(other)) {
    // do something
}
```